# How to calculate impulse in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a row telling me the values of Force, F<sub>i</sub> and I know that the time interval,Δt is 0.00025 seconds. However, I need to add up everything like this: ΣF<sub>i</sub> Δt. How can I accomplish this in Excel?

Note: I used impulse in the title because a lot of people seem to have the same problem and I didn't know the correct phrasing for the question.

Comment: Am I right in that row 1 has a bunch of numbers, row 2 should have a value incrementing by `0.00025`, row 3 should have each of the cells in row 1 multiplied by their equivilent in row 2, and then sum everything in row 3?

Comment: Yes, Paul, that would work. It's just that I was thinking of the more complicated one line formula and couldn't figure out how to write such a formula.

Comment: There probably is, but this would be the simplest way to get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A   B       A*B   Cum   Sum                     
3   0.5     2     2     C2                  
8   1.2     10    11    D2+C3                   
10  3.1     31    42    Copy the formula down the line: Copy E3 to E4:E100  
5   0.45    2     44
```

---

There are other methods too:

- `=Sumproduct(array 1, array2 ...)`
- `=Sumproduct(A2:A5,B2:B5)`